# Deleting everything after whitespace in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a massive list of dates that are in a few different formats.  What I would like to do is get rid of anything past the first whitespace character, whether it be a space, newline, tab, etc.  I've found a lot of answers detailing how to get rid of whitespace, but not much about deleting substrings based on the location of whitespace.  Example below:

```
BEFORE                   AFTER
37893                    37893
37801                    37801
37710                    37710
37620                    37620
36980                    36980
06/30/2014\nUSD          06/30/2014
03/31/2014\nUSD          03/31/2014
12/31/2013\nUSD          12/31/2013
09/30/2013\nUSD          09/30/2013
06/30/2013\nUSD          06/30/2013
03/31/2013\nUSD          03/31/2013
12/31/2012\nUSD          12/31/2012
etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example data, this would suffice:

```
LEFT(A1,10)
```

To format as dates, you could do this:

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A1,10),"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible formula solution.

`=IFERROR(--REPLACE(A1, IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(10), A1),LEN(A1)+1),LEN(A1), ""),REPLACE(A1, IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(10), A1),LEN(A1)+1),LEN(A1), ""))`

That might seem overly complex but it guards against cells that may or may not have a line feed as well as attempting to convert numbers to numbers and dates to dates while leaving text alone. You will have to format the cells to change returned values like *41820* to *6/30/2014*.

Comment: This is a good general-purpose answer, even if it's more than the OP needed.  Note that it won't work if there's a space instead of a newline, which was a requirement.  That would make the formula even hairier.

Comment: One trick I use to avoid FIND errors is to append the search string, like this:  `=FIND("x",A1&"x")`.  That's the equivalent of `=IFERROR(FIND("x",A1),LEN(A1)+1)`.  However, that wouldn't shorten your code much, since `x` is `CHAR(10)`.

Comment: +1 @RickHitchcock - good point and a quality modification suggested